# ExtJS MVC structure

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs-mvc

I'm not sure it's an acceptabale question for Stackoverflow but I have difficult time to understand the MVC structure of ExtJS so I decided to post a question, mainly because this part from the official ExtJS 4.0 tutorial "Every application works the same way so you only have to learn it once" so that is what I really want and intend to do - put more effornt on understanding how the ExtJS work and then I'm pretty sure writing the code will become a ton more easier.
  I've learned MVC moslty from CodeIgniter and it was fairly simple to understand the logic behind "M", "V" and "C". However in ExtJS it's not like that mostly because we have stores which are the topic that confuses me most.What's the logic ot having store in MVC model, shouldn't it be a part from the "M" or the "C" and if someone want to spare the time, I would pretty much appretiate an explanation why exactly we need a store defined outside the main MVC structure.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Technicaly ExtJs MVC is not an MVC in conventional way of thinking. Check out [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173334-Is-Ext-JS-really-a-MVC&s=966f8c704b9b82013148c76815334fbd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with comments by @Molecule Man and with opinions expressed in that Sencha thread.

Don't worry about naming. Think about stores as part of model in MVC. Only time you need to add special logic to the store classes if you have custom communication layer (and standard JSON, AJAX stores are not enough). And stores are not really part of your application business logic, so they don't need to be part of controllers.